# change android:Theme.Light to Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

Tags: android, android-theme

i have app which was created in android:Theme.Light. i want to change it to Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar but i get

> no resource found that matches the given name
>   'theme.appcompat.light.darkactionbar'

I have android-support-v4.jar, when i try add appcompat_v7 i get errors in codes where is something like it R..... Can I add DarkActionBar to this project without problems with codes? Without changes in code?

I have:

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

I want:

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
        res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that your application is properly linked with the Support Library, with resources ([see documentation here](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library)).

And don't forget `@style/`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

This will prevent the `no resource` error from occurring.
You might be interested in [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html) too.

Comment: i get: no resource found that matches the given name '@style/theme.appcompat.light.darkactionbar' in styles.xml

Comment: Is your application properly linked with the Support Library? (with resources, as shown here: https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library)

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this in your manifest, do the following to set the theme for the whole app:

```
 <application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" 
    ...>
```

in your XML for the specific theme, you need `@style`, so put the following:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Comment: i get: no resource found that matches the given name '@style/theme.appcompat.light.darkactionbar' in styles.xml